# Automate “add junction flag-->trace downstream-->update field”

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have two point feature classes in a geometric network, say featureA and featureB. FeatureB is downstream of featureA. And there are about 10 featureB points downstream of 1 single featureA point. I need to update a field in featureB base on a field in featureA after trace downstream by selection.

I can do this manually by place “add junction flag” on individual point in featureA, and trace downstream by selection. Then update the field in selected featureB points(fieldB2) based on the value in featureA field(fieldA1).

The problem is:
I have 2000 points in featureA. I would have to repeat above process 2000 times.  Since it’s a repetitive process, is there any way I can automate this.

1. If FieldA1 is not Null: place a junction flag-->trace downstream by selection
2. Update selected fieldB1: FieldB1=FieldA2